# C# Transpose() method to transpose rows and columns in excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I want to transpose rows and columns of an excel sheet and save it. I want to use C# transpose() method for this purpose. Can anybody tell how it can be used in C# with examples, what is the syntax, what object shoud be created to call transpose() method?

Thank you.

Comment: "I want to use C# transpose() method" - C# is a programming language and doesn't have a Transpose method.  Of course there may be .NET class libraries that have such a method - which one do you have in mind?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.transpose.aspx

Check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method is part of the Excel object model but included in C# through Visual Studio Tools for Office / Excel DNA / Managed XLL etc

```
Object[,] transposedRange = (Object[,])xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value2);
```

Then paste the transposedRange back into Excel:

```
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(transposedRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposedRange.GetUpperBound(1)) = transposedRange;
```

Comment: Thank you. But what are xlApp and rng?

Comment: xlApp is the Application object. rng is your range so Range("A1:B7") and Value2 passes it as an object array. If you are already using Excel with C# you will know about this. If not then its a big topic outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: sorry !! Pls explain what is Value2. I need it.

Comment: Value2 passes the range as an object array to Transpose()

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explicit cast to a multi dimentional Object array. Everything above works and I have just tested it.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for me either. At least if you are going to help add the variable types.

Comment: @Danrex: which variable? xlApp is your Excel Application object and is derived differently depending on which framework you use. rng is the Range you need transposing and everything else is provided.

Answer (score 8):

First you have to convert excel sheet to datatable and then programmatically transpose rows and columns of datatable.For converting excel sheet to datatable,you can search question on stackoverflow as it has lot of similar questions.For trasposing datatable below code works;

```
private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
     DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

     // Add columns by looping rows

     // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
     outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

     // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
     foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
     {
         string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
         outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
     }

     // Add rows by looping columns        
     for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
     {
         DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

         // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
         newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
         for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
         {
             string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
             newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
         }
         outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
     }

     return outputTable;
}
```

Comment: This is transposing data table. There is a method to transpose excel sheet, Transpose(). Let me know the usage, if you know.

Comment: This is the  exact same code from this article on codeproject.com: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C

Comment: Works good for transposing "data table". For me this was easier than going Excel route. Tried other solution(by InContext) but was getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'object[*,*]'".

Answer (score 0):

Transpose can be accessed as a parameter of PasteSpecial(Transpose: *whatever*).
I have answered this in full here:  [Transpose values in excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852602/transpose-values-in-excel-using-c-sharp/57046791#57046791)