# Changing a datatable from many columns to just 2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable with many columns, like so;

`Name | Age | Foo | Bar | Etc..`
`Joe  | 30  | foo | bar | Etc..`

I need to now get this datatable into just two columns consisting of just the headers followed by their values, like so;

`Header  | Value`
`Name    | Joe`
`Age     | 30`
`Foo     | foo`
`Etc...  | etc..`

This is so that a DataBinder can access it easily when the data is bound.

How can this be done, and do I need to do this at all?

**EDIT:** Including example code

`asp.net`

```
<div class="itemDetail col-s">                                                                                                                       
  <div class="itemDetailLabel">                                                                                                                            
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Caption")%>                                                                                                                        
  </div>                                                                                                                        
  <div class="itemDetailValue">                                                                                                                       
    <%# If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UIValue") Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UIValue").ToString()), "&nbsp;", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UIValue"))   %>                                                                                                                        
  </div>                                                                                                                    
</div>
```

`vb.net`

```
Dim oldDataTable As DataTable = DataSource ''Which is a datatable of a single row
Dim newDataTable As New DataTable

newDataTable.Columns.Add("Caption")
newDataTable.Columns.Add("UIValue")

''Change the single row into multiple rows

fooControl.DataSource = newDataTable
fooControl.DataBind()
```

**EDIT2:** So for those that are still learning like me, this is called transposing. Thanks for @gofal3 for pointing it out

Comment: You should add your current code to the question so that we can help you with the issue

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/816778/How-to-bind-particular-columns-of-dataset-to-a-dat

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli Do the example code samples help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transpose the DataTable. As far as I know there is no built in method, but you have to write your own code to do so.
But there are a lot of examples how other did it. eg: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C or [Transpose a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817061/transpose-a-datatable)

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know there was a name for it, which is probably why my searching wasn't returning anything of value.