# Dynamic Convert Row to Column in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to convert Row to Column, actually I can implement a Static row to column as below, but it only works if I know the row position beforehand, so does anyone know how to dynamically convert a Row to Column in Linq?

This is the [below table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bog70.png)

```
ItemCode  LOC001    LOC002   LOC003     
 AAA      10         11        12 
 BBB      13         31        14
 CCC      15         18        0
```

This is the Static Code:

```
var table=(from x in Mst_LocationItems

group x by x.ItemCode into gr
select new
       {
          ItemCode=gr.Key,
          LOC001 = gr.Where(x=>x.LocationID == "LOC001").Sum(x=>x.Reorder),
          LOC002 = gr.Where(x=>x.LocationID == "LOC002").Sum(x=>x.Reorder),
          LOC003 = gr.Where(x=>x.LocationID == "LOC003").Sum(x=>x.Reorder)
       }).ToList();

           table.Dump();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [transpose a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817061/transpose-a-datatable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817061/transpose-a-datatable)

Comment: Could you give me more details for my code

Comment: Can you provide more details about what "dynamically" means to you?