# How to transpose data in Linq?

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I get below data from Postgresql table, need to sum the ListDate field for each month and transpose.
I tried this link [Transpose a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817061/transpose-a-datatable) using linq query , but not feasible or right approach to achieve it.

| ListDate | MM | FC | AMS | KS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 12 | 13 | 34 | 26 |
| 2023-01-01 | 22 | 23 | 44 | 46 |
| 2022-12-01 | 32 | 13 | 34 | 26 |
| 2023-12-01 | 42 | 13 | 64 | 16 |
| 2023-11-10 | 62 | 13 | 94 | 36 |
| 2023-11-23 | 02 | 13 | 34 | 46 |

**Expected Result -**

| . | JAN-23 | DEC-22 | NOV-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MM | 34 | 74 | 64 |
| FC | 36 | 26 | 26 |
| AMS | 78 | 98 | 118 |
| KS | 72 | 42 | 82 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate - Transposing a List<List<string>> using LINQ C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484996/rotate-transposing-a-listliststring-using-linq-c-sharp)

Comment: This is not transposing but *pivoting* and LINQ doesn't have a built-in method for it. There are many questions and answer on LINQ + pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first point:**

`12-01-2023` should be `2022-12-01` in order, the question data to match the `Expected Result`.

If we have the following list:

```
    public class item
    {
        public item(string _dt,int _MM,int _FC,int _AMS,int _KS)
        {
            dt = _dt;
            MM = _MM;
            FC = _FC;
            AMS = _AMS;
            KS = _KS;
        }
        public string dt { get;  set; }
        public int MM { get; set; }
        public int FC { get; set; }
        public int AMS { get; set; }
        public int KS { get; set; }
    }


List<item> _list=new List<item>();
_list.Add(new item("2023-01-01", 12, 13, 24, 26));
_list.Add(new item("2023-01-01", 22, 23, 44, 46));
_list.Add(new item("2022-12-01", 32, 13, 24, 26));
_list.Add(new item("2022-12-01", 42, 13, 64, 26));
_list.Add(new item("2023-11-10", 62, 13, 94, 36));
_list.Add(new item("2023-11-23", 02, 13, 34, 46));
```

- We can use `Substring(0,7)` to group by year and month.
- Now the key of group by `year-month(ex: 2023-12)`. We can get the month name using `DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName`
- and calculate the `last two digits of the year using the substring(2,2)`
- And finally, `collect the parameters` and `convert them into a list`

  ```
        var result = _list
           .GroupBy(g =>
               g.dt.Substring(0,7)
           )

           .Select(group => new
           {
               dateOfMonth = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(int.Parse(group.Key.Split('-')[1]))
                + "-" + group.Key.Split('-')[0].Substring(2,2),
               MM = group.Sum(s => s.MM),
               FC = group.Sum(s => s.FC),
               AMS = group.Sum(a => a.AMS),
               KS = group.Sum(c => c.KS)
           }).ToList();
  ```

***Result:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is my class

---

```
 public class Data
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int MM { get; set; }
        public int FC { get; set; }
        public int AMS { get; set; }
        public int KS { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
var dataList=new List<Data>
        {
            new Data
            {
                 AMS=34, Date="2023-01-01", FC=13, KS=26, MM=12
            },  new Data
            {
                 AMS=44, Date="2023-01-01", FC=23, KS=46, MM=22
            },  new Data
            {
                 AMS=34, Date="2022-12-01", FC=13, KS=26, MM=32
            },  new Data
            {
                 AMS=64, Date="2023-12-01", FC=13, KS=16, MM=42
            },  new Data
            {
                 AMS=94, Date="2023-11-10", FC=13, KS=36, MM=62
            },  new Data
            {
                 AMS=34, Date="2023-11-23", FC=13, KS=46, MM=02
            }
        }.ToList();
```

---

```
  var query = dataList
    .GroupBy(g =>
        g.Date.ToString()
    )
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Date= DateTime.Parse(group.Key).ToString("dd MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        MM = group.Sum(s => s.MM),
        FC = group.Sum(s => s.FC),
        AMS = group.Sum(a => a.AMS),
        KS = group.Sum(c => c.KS)
    });
```

Comment: Kindly explain the code with comment so any user can understand what your does in every step.