# Transpose values in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, transpose

I saw this link - [C# Transpose() method to transpose rows and columns in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838403/c-sharp-transpose-method-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-excel-sheet) in stackoverflow and this is what I am trying to do. But the guy is pretty unhelpful in the answers as he does not provide the full information needed. I am simply wanting to transpose cells A9:B15 in my excel sheet and then copy them either into a new xls file, a new worksheet, or better yet delete the current worksheet contents and replace it with the newly transposed paste contents. Clearly it can be done through the WorksheetFunction.Transpose method but I can't seem to get it to work as I don't know what rng or value2 are? I could create a datatable but surly using this method seems a more appropriate way of doing it. Here is the code from the stackoverflow question. .

```
Object[,] transposedRange = (Object[,])xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value2);

xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(transposedRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposedRange.GetUpperBound(1)) = transposedRange;
```

Here is my code so far:

```
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Debugging\Debugging\test.htm");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = excel.get_Range("A9:B15");
        Object[,] transposeRange = (Object[,])excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng);
        transposeRange = excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(transposeRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposeRange.GetUpperBound(1));
        wb.SaveAs(@"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Debugging\Debugging\testing.xls");
```

Not sure if I have done the rng right. I am so confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long time ago but I will let my sollution anyway.

Refs:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

The trick here is to get the _Application Variable

in case you are using VSTO ADDIN with Workbook you can do like this:

```
var app = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Parent as _Application;
```

For other kind of project do like this:

```
_Application app2 = new Excel.Application();
```

My sample (sheet1 is my worksheet):

```
        var sheet1 = Globals.Planilha1;
        var arr = new string[] 
        {
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test4",
            "test5",
            "test6",
        };
        
        // For VSTO ADDINS with Workbook
        //var app = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Parent as _Application;

        // For any kind of Excel Interop project
        _Application app = new Excel.Application();

        sheet1.Range["A1:A" + arr.Length].Value = app.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr);
```

The Transpose function can only deal with arrays, lists won't work.

Just place the array inside the app.WorksheetFunction.Transpose function and it will work pretty well.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you need to do this in C#?

If what you want is just what you state, VBA code can accomplish this also.  Just

- read the transposed range into a variant array
- clear the worksheet
- write the variant array back to the worksheet at the cell of your choice.
- Note that when you write the variant array back to the worksheet, the destination range must be the same size as the array.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub TransposeRange()
    Dim RGtoTranspose As Range
    Dim V As Variant
Set RGtoTranspose = Range("A9:B15")
V = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(RGtoTranspose)

Cells.Clear
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(V, 1), UBound(V, 2)).Value = V

End Sub
```

Comment: So why would I choose VBA over C#?

Comment: I think the question should be why would you use something other than a simple Excel macro to perform this task?  I'm not saying there may not be good reasons; just wonder what they are.  If you are using Excel anyway.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, b/c when making an excel file in a C# application it is a lot of extra work to add a module, add the macro then run it via C# to apply the formatting etc. Also , when you want to create a complex formatted file to be printed out as a PDF file, sometimes Excel is the only way to go and it has to be done all in the C# app.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, which explicitly asks for a C# solution.

Comment: @colmbhandal he also wrote that he could not get the `worksheetfunction.transpose` function to work. The answer demonstrates a method of doing that and might be useful to others looking for the same issue solution

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it is a good answer, to a different question. Perhaps this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910284/how-to-copy-a-whole-sheet-and-transpose-paste-into-another-sheet-in-vba.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Since it's been 4 1/2 years without a response from the original poster, either he was satisfied with the answer or solved his problem in another fashion.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Maybe, maybe not. But later users looking for an answer to this problem e.g. me waste time scrolling to a completely irrelevant answer like this. SO is a public community and not a private one to one chat.

Comment: It might not be C#, but this is a good solution to the same problem I have and VBA is quite straightforward to convert to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like nobody actually bothered to answer this and its still the top search engine hit for this issue (@ July 2019, go figure...!), so here's my 2 cents... 
I did not understand the hype about the WorksheetFunction.Transpose method. "Objectifying" things around isn't perhaps the cleanest way to go about this, particularly when using the Excel Interop anyway. At the end of the day, Transpose has been a dynamic parameter of the PasteSpecial() method since time immemorial. So why not use it as such? I think this was what prompted some people to suggest using VBA instead of C#... Anyway, this code works and does what the question requires methinks:

First get the references right...

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then try this...

```
    string filePath = @"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Debugging\Debugging\test.htm";
    string savePath = @"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Debugging\Debugging\testing.xls";

    var excelApp = new Excel.Application()
    {
        Visible = true      //This is optional
    };
    Workbooks workbook = excelApp.Workbooks;
    workbook.Open(filePath);

    Range range = excelApp.get_Range("A9:B15");
    range.Copy();

    excelApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Transpose: true);     //voila... :)
    range.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);     //delete original range 

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(savePath))           //is the workbook already saved?
    {
        excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(savePath);   //save
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", savePath);    //or do whatever...
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
```

It could be simplified further... but it is more readable like this.