# How to copy a whole sheet and transpose paste into another sheet in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Working environment:Excel 2013.

**Target:**

1. copy a whole sheet
2. create another sheet
3. transpose paste the copied sheet into this new sheet.

the code that i am using is as below:

```
Worksheets("Sheet4").Copy
Worksheets("Master").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

however when i run it, i got an error

> application defined or object defined error

Anyone can help me to figure out why?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet4").Copy` copies the sheet to a new workbook, not to the clipboard, so there is nothing to paste when you get to the next line.  You won't be able to paste 1048576 rows x 16384 columns into an area of 16384 rows x 1048576 columns anyway - Excel only handles a maximum of 16384 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateAndCopyTran()

Dim ws As Worksheet

' create a new worksheet, and name it "Master"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
ws.Name = "Master"

' copy the UsedRange and Transpose
Worksheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! another question is that where do you usually find out the code? I mean is there any VBA library?

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the cells in Sheet4, not the sheet itself, so you need to call the copy method of a range/cells.

Similarly, the PasteSpecial method needs to be called on a range object, rather than a sheet object.

You could try this, for example:

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Copy
    Worksheets("Master").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That really help me a lot.