# C# - Transpose excel table using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I should transpose a table of an excel sheet in c#. There is a method to do it into the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` api, or any other method to do this?

### Edit

This is my code:

```
string pathFile, range;   

pathFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" + fileName;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(pathFile);
Console.WriteLine("Inserire il range delle celle da copiare(sono tutti uguali): ");
range = Console.ReadLine();

Excel.Range rgn = app.get_Range(range);
Object[,] transposeRange = (Object[,])app.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rgn);
transposeRange = app.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(transposeRange.GetUpperBound(0), transposeRange.GetUpperBound(1));
```

Comment: You need to ask a more clear question with more detail.

Comment: Because I really can't tell what you're asking, I can only provide you this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetclass.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1  Check the copy method.

Comment: @Jaberwocky I edited the post by entering the code that I try to write. I hope you can better understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Transpose method exists in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library. You may see the usage of it at the below link :

[C# Transpose() method to transpose rows and columns in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838403/c-sharp-transpose-method-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-excel-sheet)

Comment: I have tried to follow the explanation that was given to the question you linked to me but without getting successful. I edited the post with the code I wrote.